# Erdas Imagine 2014 - Mosaicing SPOT 6 image tiles with seamless colour generation

Tags: erdas-imagine

I have several SPOT 6 image tiles and every time I mosaic the images the final image comes out with different colors, with each depicting the various tiles(image scenes) used in the mosaic. The overlapping areas also appear very visible in the image. Even when I apply color balancing and histogram match options, the results doesn't change much and its not even getting better. I also tried using breakpoints to edit the parameters of individual images, yet it still not working.

I have also tried to use ER Mapper to solve the problem, yet it still not working.
Please can any one help with a solution?